# Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Check-in Policy not visible

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, policy

I'm a TFS administrator for my project and I want to implement a few check-in policies to remember developers to follow specific procedures.

However, when I got to the Settings->Source Control dialog. I only see the tabs "File Types" and "Workspace Settings". There is no "Check-in Policy" tab.

I have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 2, full installation

I checked the permissions and all the roles I'm member of has the Edit project-level information permission as either "Allow", or "Inherited Allow".

I could not find specific information as to what I may be missing that is causing this tab not to be there.

Does any one of you have an idea of what I may be missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you must be admin on the Team Project level. You may also look into TFS power tools, although they shouldn't be needed to make the required changes. 4

Are you using a Local instance of TFS or are you using Visual Studio Online?

Comment: I am a member of the "Admin Team" on the Team project level. I'm using a local instance of TFS.

Comment: Ahhhh, I was accessing the wrong dialog. I was accessing the Settings under Team Project Collection according to the instructions [here](http://www.devart.com/review-assistant/docs/index.html?adding_code_review_policy_to_tfs_project.html), but I should be accessing the settings from TEAM->Team Project Settings-> Source Control...